# To stop document.click function on key up

Tags: javascript, jquery

To hide a div on click on the rest of the page I used

```
    $('#display').click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
     });


  $(document).click(function(){

       $('#display').slideUp();

});
```

Now I want make the function document.click work only if a user is not typing any text in text box  with id "mse".

```
      <input type="text" id="mse" name="search">
```

I tried like this:

```
      $(document).click(function(){
         if($( "#mse" ).keyup()){
             //do nothing
       }else{
        $('#display').slideUp();
       }
     });
```

But it doesn't worked.

Help me to overcome this problem.

My total code is:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#mse").keyup(function() 
        {
           var searchbox = $(this).val();
           var dataString = 'searchword='+ searchbox;
           if(searchbox=='')
             {}
           else
            {
             $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "search.jsp",
                  data: dataString,
                  cache: false,
                  success: function(html)
                  {

                   $("#smartscreen").html(html).show();
                   }
             });
         }return false; 
       });

       $('#mse').focus(function(){
             $('#display' ).css( "display", "block" );
       });

       $('#display').click(function(e){
              e.stopPropagation();
         });



        });

            $(document).click(function(e){

                $('#display').slideUp();



              });
```

Comment: The click shouldn't work only if the textbox is empty OR only if the user is not currently typing something (i.e. click and keypress simultaneously) ?

Comment: The logic in this situation (at least the way it's explained) makes no real sense.  You are either typing or clicking.  Not both.  What situation will you ever be in where your hand is typing a word while you start clicking your mouse?

Comment: What does "typing any text" mean to you? (A) Focus is in the field you mention; (B) One or more keys is actually down, I.e a keydown event has occurred without a corresponding keyup; (C) That field is not empty; (D) A keystroke occurred in that field within the last x milliseconds; (E) All of the above;(F) None of the above.

Comment: The one comment/question to rule them all^

Comment: @nnnnnn When I focused on text box the document.click is occurring.So A option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to turn the document's click event on and off.  Here are the ingredients for that:

[.on() with namespacing of the event](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names)

[.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

[.focus()](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) and [.blur()](http://api.jquery.com/blur/)

Then, depending on what you need, do something like this: when the "mse" element gets focused, turn off the document's click event.  When the "mse" element gets blurred, turn the document's click event back on.  [Example in this JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zHuTa/)

relevant code from the JS Fiddle:

```
$('#mse').focus(function(){
    $(document).off('click.slider');
    $('#display').css('display', 'block');
});

$('#mse').blur(function(){
    $(document).on('click.slider', function(e){
        $('#display').slideUp();
    });
});
```